# How to set the read ACL on container in open stack swift such that allow Read for all users and deny for one user

Tags: swift, containers, acl, openstack-swift

How to set the read ACL in open stack swift such that allow Read for all users and deny for one user.

For example, i have one container i.e container10. suppose five users are there u1,u2,u3,u4,u5. All having the member role only. I want to set acl on container10, so that u1,u2,u3 can stat, and list ...but u4 can't.

Comment: What did you try so far? Please take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: --read acl ".r:*,.rlistings, my_tenant:-block_user" . Here i m trying to block the user block_user from my_tenant.

Comment: I have also tried 
 
--read acl ".r:*,.rlistings,-block_user"

Comment: Edit your question to add those two things, explain why it did not work, and what you expect from us.